# How can I reverse the effect of geopands.affine_transform?

Tags: geopandas, affine-transformation

Beginner question here... I'm a little unclear on how to go about reversing a transformation of a matrix from the format of Ax=b (or if it's possible for that matter).

I started out with a 6x6 matrix `A` and target vector `b`, I can compute the missing vector using `Ax=b`

I then applied the points of the solved vector `x` to my dataset using an affine transformation and applied it with `geopandas.series.affine_transform` feeding in the 6 points of `x` so I have now shifted the original points.

Since then some noise has been introduced to the points. My goal is to reverse this transformation of the points by applying some matrix or vector prevoiusly calculated to revert to supposed original locations. I can then get a visual look to see how far they are off.

In essence, how do I reverse the effects of the `affine_transform` that was applied? I still have the values for `A` `x` and `b` handy.